# Obama's 2011 ban on Iraqi refuges vs Trump's ban

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, immigration, barack-obama

Quoting [ABC News](http://abcnews.go.com/Blotter/al-qaeda-kentucky-us-dozens-terrorists-country-refugees/story?id=20931131):

> As a result of the Kentucky case, the State Department stopped processing Iraq refugees for six months in 2011, federal officials told ABC News

Trump's January 25 ban applied to Visa holders and, according to [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2017/01/28/politics/green-card-donald-trump-travel-ban/), Green Card holders, as well.

My question is.: did Obama's 2011 ban apply to visa holders and green card holders like Trump's recent ban did?

Comment: cross-site dupe: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36956/did-president-obama-institut-an-immigration-restrictions-in-2011-that-is-similar

Comment: The January 25 order doesn't apply to Green Card holders (and Obama's 2011 order did not either). There has been a festival of fake news during the week end.

Comment: @Joël Green card holders were however affected by the order, and some administration officials did say that it would apply to them.  I think it's rather less a case of fake news than it is of disarray and confusion in the administration, on account of a hastily executed and poorly implemented order.

Comment: > Trump's January 25 ban applied to Visa holders and, it does not apply to green card holders, as it has been clarified a few times. The fury is manufactured by people with an agenda onto people not sufficient to see through that agenda.

Comment: @dannyf: That's wrong. The order DID apply to green card holders. Otherwise, the Secretary of Homeland Security John Kelly wouldn't have had to several days later [use his power](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2017/01/29/statement-secretary-john-kelly-entry-lawful-permanent-residents-united-states) under section 3(g) of the executive order to specifically deem entry of green card holders to be "in the national interest" (which is a term from the executive order) as an exception to let them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no primary source to unambiguously answer this. All we have is hearsay from either journalists, or administration officials - usually from 2013, well after the fact. It wasn't done via published executive order.

Having said that,

- Pretty much none of the sources I ever saw (many linked [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/36952/1044)), ever mentioned anything **except refugee** processing halt.

  (whether you want to call it a halt, a ban or a slowdown is semantics, really; but halt seems the most accurate term given the available details).
- Logically it makes sense. The whole event was precipitated by laxly-vetted refugees having been admitted who shouldn't have been. Green card holders aren't vetted at all, so they would have any reason to be included in that specific move by Obama administration.

Comment: The vetting process for refugees took 18 to 24 months and needed sign-off of dozens of organizations, both domestic and international.  The claim that refugees are or were "laxly-vetted" is without factual foundation.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet A lengthy procedure doesn't guarantee anything. Those procedures can easily be done in a very laxly way, especially when done in large numbers - E.g. rubber-stamping every sign-off without even reading it. The "laxly-vetted" usually is based on hindsight, by pointing at people who made it through the procedure but in hind-sight should not have.

Comment: @Sjoerd - not sure why you assume that's the case.  There is no indication that it is.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - don't know why that commenter assumed that's the case, but I know why I did - extensive personal experience with INS/DHS. They are overly anal in some cases and absolutely ridiculously easy going in others - sometimes depending on individual employee.

Comment: @user4012 - "personal impression" is often completely unrelated to actuality.  However, assuming your observations are accurate and valid, where those related to the refugee vetting process?  Making another assumption that they were, do the actions supported by people who offer that reason address that issue, at all?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - first, part of them were explicitly related to refugee process, yes. And even those that weren't, are valid because it's the same distracted bureaucrats doing both. it's not like there's some special super alert Alastor Moody constant vigilance subset of employees dedicated to only refugee vetting and no other immigrants :)

Comment: @user4012 - Since we are talking about dozens of agencies, domestic and international, that sign off, I'm not sure how that makes the entire process and all steps suspect.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - the problem is that you don't need ENTIRE process to be problematic. Just one weak link. The checks aren't all redundant. **The end result (terrorists actually being admitted) speaks for itself**

Comment: @user4012 - You're making the argument that the vetting process isn't 100% bullet-proof in certainty.  Not that it is lax.  And, again, unless you can point to actions taken that remedy flaws (and I'm not sure how not including countries that HAVE actually had their citizens strike us on US, soil, and only "banning" ones that haven't qualifies), it's more of a pretext than an actual legitimate claim.

Comment: Please reference actual terrorist attacks in the US initiated by terrorists who slipped through the current refugee vetting process.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - The linked (and asked) event was explicitly about discovery of terrorists (who committed attacks in Iraq). Unless of course victims being Iraqis somehow makes it OK and the perps not terrorists in your mind?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - remedy was to slow process down. Faster/cheaper/better/pick-two is not just limited to building spacecraft.

Comment: @user4012 - again, a claim without foundation. I'm not seeing anything to indicate that anything was rushed.